# Pink line on screen

Tags: display, hardware-failure

A pink line appear on my laptop Sony Vaio screen few days back.

I tried to resolve this by formatting my machine but it still appear. I think this is a hardware issue.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Sounds like a display failure.

Comment: Does it appear always or if you tilt your screen it disappears? If this is the case, the ribbon cable might not be connecting perfectly with the motherboard.

Comment: It always appear on my screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most likely related to a physical hardware issue. You will have to replace the component in question, which will require more trouble shooting on your end to find out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You have a row of dead pixels. There is a program that is supposed to "excite" the pixels to coax them to working again, it may be worth a try, the times I have tried, it did not do it for me.
You will need to replace the LCD panel. It is an easy (most of the time) DIY replacement.

Answer (score -1):

While you are searching for a solution, you can also install [flux](https://justgetflux.com/) to temporary calibrate screen color.

Comment: f.lux does not temporarily calibrate screen color. What f.lux does is changes the screen color by a small amount to compensate for changes in the color of sunlight at different hours of the day. Beyond that adjusting the entire color of the screen by a small amount would not solve or even ameliorate the problem of a line artifact appearing on the screen.

Comment: yes , you are right about this. but this functionality also can help to calibrate screen colors. I tell you this because actually my screen has this problem and I calibrated it with this program until I am going to fix it. If you know better program, please let me know!